# Module has no attribute... unsure

Tags: python

In an effort to create a simple script for another question to highlight an issue I am having, I ran into this confusing problem. My code won't run. I read several other Stack Overflow answers and ensured that I am not using a pre-defined class. I am also not doing a cyclical import. I have no idea. I am new to Python.

TestClass.py:

```
class TestClass:
    test_number = 10000  # Default score limit

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def check_test_number(self):
        # this needs to be an instance method
        print(TestClass.test_number)
```

TestScript.py:

```
import TestClass


def main():
    t1 = TestClass.TestClass()
    print(TestClass.test_number)
    print(t1.check_test_number())
    TestClass.test_number = 500
    print(TestClass.test_number)
    print(t1.check_test_number())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I recieve this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'TestClass' has no attribute 'test_number'
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: No this didn't answer my question. If I replace import TestClass with from src import TestClass I get the exact same error.

Comment: `print(TestClass.test_number)` -> `print(TestClass.TestClass.test_number)`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Why is the output  10k, 10k, none, 500, 500, none? Why are there nones? This is my REAL question that I can't ask for 24 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the fields `test_number` and `score_limit` on lines `print(TestClass.test_number)` and `TestClass.test_number= 500` like this: `TestClass.TestClass.test_number` or use expression `from *your_file* import *ClassName*`. In your code you're trying to refer not to a class field, but to a method or variable in the file TestClass.py. I advise you to use snake_case to name `.py` files to avoid confusions. I think your code can be rewritten like this (with renaming TestClass.py):

test_script.py

```
from test_class import TestClass


def main():
    t1 = TestClass()
    print(TestClass.test_number)
    print(t1.check_test_number())
    TestClass.test_number= 500
    print(TestClass.test_number)
    print(t1.check_test_number())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I find this very confusing coming from Java and C# though.

Comment: Would you look at my comment above and amended code? I expect an output of 10k,10k,10k, 500,500,500.

Comment: Sure, to get this result you need to add `return self.test_number` to tne `check_test_number()` method. To be honest, I did not quite understand what the point of this script is and I did not find your previous question

Comment: I'm a complete idiot and it seems that this test script did not accurately describe my true problem after all. LOL. This script was an attempt to simplify my problem. The problem I have in my full program is that I change the test_number to 500 from a different class, but an instance of that class still was showing 10k. It may be that I was wrong by not using (TestClass.TestClass.test_number) in my real program.

Comment: I can confirm my true problem was caused by not using TestClass.TestClass.test_number. Thank you so much!